# Use of ostream_iterator with an auto type?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, ostream

In my college exam preparation I'm supposed to use ostream_operator with "auto" keyword.

Below is what I tried but the "auto" word is underlined in red with the error stating that `auto is not allowed here'.

I need `auto` here because the class attribute within the vector are of another class' type and is not recognized from within this current class.

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& COUT, const Nastava& obj)
{
    COUT << "<" << obj._datum << " - " << obj._satnica << "> <" << obj._prostorija << "> " << " <" << obj._predavac << "> " << obj._tipNastave;
    COUT << endl << obj._predmet->Info();

    ostream_iterator<auto> outit(COUT, "\n");
    copy(obj._prisutni->begin(), obj._prisutni->end(), outit);


    return COUT;
}
```

Comment: Try `ostream_iterator<decltype(*xxx->begin())>`.

Comment: @KerrekSB I can't say it worked -- I needed to overload both `operator=` and `operator<<` for this external class (whose objects are supposed to be printed from the vector attribute) but the content in vector is not coming out at all.

Comment: @KerrekSB: the `decltype(*it)` is bound to yield a reference type. At the very least it would be necessary to `std::decay_t<T>‘ the result.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Ah yes, I was suspecting something like that. It'll get messy. `ostream_iterator<std::decay_t<decltype(*xxx->begin())>>`, and then we don't support C++14 so `decay_t` won't exist, etc.

Comment: @KerrekSB: the easy way out: `auto x = *xxx->begin();` and then using `decltype(x)`. It does an unnecessary copy, though.

Comment: So what's the verdict here? I don't necessarily need to make this work on my machine and VS, because if my professor gives us an exam with this I suppose university machines should have installed such VS version that supports it. Or, is it not really about VS/C++ version?